# How to use Expect in a Bash script

Tags: bash, expect

I am trying to write a script that pulls the latest version of my software from a Git repository and updates the configuration files. When pulling from the repository though, I have to enter a password. I want the script to automate everything, so I need it to automatically fill it in for me. I found this site that explained how to use Expect to look for the password prompt and send the password. I can't get it to work though.

Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set password [lrange $argv 0 0]
set timeout -1

clear
echo "Updating Source..."
cd sourcedest
git pull -f origin master

match_max 100000
# Look for passwod prompt
expect "*?assword:*"
# Send password aka $password
send -- "$password\r"
# send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to gui
send -- "\r"
expect eof

git checkout -f master
cp Config/database.php.bak Config/database.php
cp webroot/index.php.bak webroot/index.php
cp webroot/js/config.js.bak webroot/js/config.js
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the site I got it from: http://bash.cyberciti.biz/security/expect-ssh-login-script/

Comment: Suppose you forgot the spawn.

Comment: i'm not wanting that part. I'm running this inside my local machine.

Comment: No git, cd and cp are  no valid expect commands. You need to spawn a shell for it.

Comment: wait, you mean i'd have to use send for every line???

Comment: No. But you need to use spawn for the git and cp lines. Instead of cd I would add the git-dir to the git command.

Comment: so `spawn git pull -f origin master` ?

Comment: That looks good. As I wrote maybe you need to set --git-dir

Comment: ok, i tried that, but it tells me that's not a git repo, but if I cd to it it works. :p

Comment: Why do you always have to enter a password when pulling from the remote repository?  Is it an ssh or http based remote?  Are you sure ssh keys aren't an option?  What about storing a username and password in your `.netrc` file?  There may be multiple ways of making this whole `expect` script unnecessary.

Answer (score 22):

This is pretty much taken from the comments, with a few observations of my own. But nobody seems to want to provide a real answer to this, so here goes:

Your problem is you have an *Expect* script and you're treating it like a *Bash* script. Expect doesn't know what `cd`, `cp`, and `git` mean. Bash does. You want a Bash script that makes a call to Expect. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

password="$1"
sourcedest="path/to/sourcedest"
cd $sourcedest

echo "Updating Source..."
expect <<- DONE
  set timeout -1

  spawn git pull -f origin master
  match_max 100000

  # Look for password prompt
  expect "*?assword:*"
  # Send password aka $password
  send -- "$password\r"
  # Send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to the GUI
  send -- "\r"
  expect eof
DONE

git checkout -f master
cp Config/database.php.bak Config/database.php
cp webroot/index.php.bak webroot/index.php
cp webroot/js/config.js.bak webroot/js/config.js
```

However, as larsks pointed out in the comments, you might be better off using SSH keys. Then you could get rid of the `expect` call altogether.