# Passing values that the commands in a shell script are going to expect

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script which has a bunch of commands, out of which some commands expect user input. For instance, if I want to push my changes to git, I use the command `git push`, which then asks me for the username and password. A traditional shell script halts for user input when it expects username. What I want to do is, pass this username and password as a command line argument, and the command should pick up that value.

Please note: 
1. The above question is not in context to git, I have just used it as an example. I understand that I can always store my credentials in the configuration file specific to git, and then it won't prompt me for the credentials. I only want to know the technique of how such thing is done.

2. Once again, in regards to the example above, security is not a concern. Currently, I am not concerned about passing the password as clear text from command line.

I tried to google it, but didn't get satisfactory results. Any ideas on this will be helpful.

Comment: What your talking about is using [Positional Parameters](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_wss0120.php) and a Google search for bash positional parameters or search for passing arguments to shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the "expect" command to send password.

Refer this answer
[using expect in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393848/using-expect-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

Command name parameters in shell are referenced by `$n` where `n` is the number of parameter starting with 0 which is the name of the script. For instance the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0 #name of the script
echo $1 #the first parameter
echo $2 #the second parameter
```

will print name of the program and parameters