# couldn't read file :expect error in a bash script

Tags: bash, expect

I am facing error in my below expect embedded bash script.
When i run it,I get the below error and the script ends
Even though I am giving the arguments on commandline.The expect send is unable to get the $site variable

```
./expect_delete "password" usa rvomero
```

> "Enter site name for Username: couldn't read file "site": no such file or directory"

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
password="$1"
me=`whoami`
site="$2"
list="$3"
echo $site $list
for i in `echo $list`
do
/tools/cfr/bin/expect -c "
set timeout 10
spawn <fullpathtoanotherbashscript> $site $i
expect "Enter site name for $me: "
send "$site\r"
expect "Enter password for $me: "
send "$password\r"
expect eof
"
done
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: As a side note, are you sure the -c flag for expect allows multiline commands ? If this causes the issue, maybe you could use a heredoc, as shown in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393848/using-expect-in-bash-script). I suspect your multiple " might be causing the problem

Comment: glad you solved your issue :) I'll mark your question as duplicate though, as you used the question I linked to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off encapsulating the expect script in ' so there isn't any shell expansion going on and getting your variables in to it by simply exporting them -

```
export USER=fred

expect -c '
  set user $env(USER)
  ....
'
```